# How do I interact with other applications in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, ipc

I want to know if there is some way to change the positioning of other applications is C++. What I want to do is move the active window on the screen. For example I want to move Firefox in a circular move. At 2:17 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLqPepLhDTY&list=WL8D6E1A188FBFE181 the browser moves, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You should first use [`FindWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function get HWND of your window. Then you can simply use [`SetWindowPos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`MoveWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with found HWND to change position.

Answer (score 0):

*On linux, mac and FreeBSD:* Here's a quick script that uses [`xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml) to slide the chrome browser along some trajectory:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read x y
do 
    xdotool search --class google-chrome windowmove $x $y
    sleep 0.001
done <<TRAJECTORY
624 624
634 614
644 624
654 614
664 624
674 614
684 624
694 614
704 624
TRAJECTORY
```

Notes

- I've made the trajectory pretty boring
  You can use some elementary trigs to make the motion circular though. The sample shows you can even feed shapes from a list
- The example hardcodes the target window (but you could use e.g. `selectwindow` to have the user click any window to operate on)
  Again your imagination is the limit

Comment: interesting, but way outside OP request... (no c++ and windows stuff here)

Comment: @pepper_chico Well. I'm answering his question, not the tags. Often there's a degree of [X/Y asking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) involved. Also, nothing precludes him from (a) driving `xdotool` from [tag:c++] or (b) using `xlib`+`xtst` directly from c++, using [the source code of `xdotool`](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/#idp9392) as a reference. The license does not seem to preclude this even for commercial applications.

Comment: doesnt seem to be a clean solution for me; invoking external programs to solve problems is IMO dirty.

Comment: @Paranaix I didn't know that meddling with the window position of another process, without that process cooperating could be "clean" xD Besides, you haven't read the `(b)` part of my comment. This is a very concrete example of how it's done. If the OP likes it, he'll be able to code this in his preferred way.

Comment: @sehe Well a window usually belongs more to an OS as to a process, thus there ARE clean ways to do suchs a task, namely to invoke the provided OS functions. And though I personally do not like this solution I accept the point, that it is a solution, therefor I also havent downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using `FindWindow` on a window you didn't make is difficult because you need the class name used on that window.  Use `EnumWindows` instead.  Here's a code sample that searches for and closes any window with "Firefox" in it's name.  Continually send [WM_MOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of WM_CLOSE to move the window.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

HWND windowHandle;

BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR title[500];
    ZeroMemory(title, sizeof(title));

    //string strTitle;

    GetWindowText(hWnd, title, sizeof(title)/sizeof(title[0]));

    //_tprintf(_T("Found window: %s\n"), title);

    //strTitle += title; // Convert to std::string
    if(_tcsstr(title, _T("Firefox")))
    {
        windowHandle = hWnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        windowHandle = NULL;
        EnumWindows(MyEnumProc, 0);

        cout << endl << endl << "Desired window handle: " << windowHandle << endl << "Sending WM_CLOSE message..." << endl;
        SendMessage(windowHandle, WM_CLOSE, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One can look up the class name, besides `FindWindow` can also search for names.

Comment: Which is often more reliable as any window could have the title "Firefox"

Comment: But why do you have to send WM_MOVE continuously and not just once?

Comment: @gdany If you only want to move the window once, they only send it once.  I was under the impression you wanted to move the window in some sort of pattern (like a circle).

Comment: Yea, I worked a little at it and I realized that's why the while loop was there. :D

Comment: @gdany Actually, the loop is there to continue searching for the window if it can't find it the first time (closing it as soon as it opens) - not to continuously send the message.  The way you posted searches once and then continuously sends the message while mine continuously searches until it finds the window it wants and then sends the message once.

Comment: @Proxy your right. I just moved windowHandle = NULL; and EnumWindows(MyEnumProc, 0); inside the loop and it works even if I close and open firefox again

Answer (score 0):

Wow, thank you guys, I wasn't expecting to answer so fast. I will try and see which code would be best to use. It finally works the way I want it. The code looks like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")

HWND windowHandle;

BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TCHAR title[500];
    ZeroMemory(title, sizeof(title));

    //string strTitle;

    GetWindowText(hWnd, title, sizeof(title)/sizeof(title[0]));

    //_tprintf(_T("Found window: %s\n"), title);

    //strTitle += title; // Convert to std::string
    if(_tcsstr(title, _T("Firefox")))
    {
        windowHandle = hWnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
int xLoc = 10;
int yLoc = 50;

int getXLoc(){
    if(xLoc<70&&yLoc<=30){
        xLoc += 1;
        Sleep(10);
    }else if(yLoc>30){
        xLoc -= 1;
        Sleep(10);
    }
    return xLoc;
}
int getYLoc(){
    if(yLoc>10&&xLoc<30){
        yLoc -= 1;
        Sleep(10);
    }else if(xLoc>=30&&yLoc<70){
        yLoc += 1;
        Sleep(10);
    }
    return yLoc;
}

int main()
{
    windowHandle = NULL;
    EnumWindows(MyEnumProc, 0);
    while(true){
        MoveWindow(windowHandle, getXLoc(), getYLoc(), 1220, 930, false);
        Sleep(5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```